# Switch won't turn on after AC adapter error

Tags: nintendo-switch

I was charging my Switch (Without the dock, with the wire) with a charger that was extremely sensitive. I heard a quiet, "BZZT" and my Nintendo Switch displayed an error message saying to hold the power button for 12 seconds. It didn't work. I don't want to risk charging it with that charger, and I don't want to send it back. Is there an easy fix for this? Also, the system was at about 38% and it shouldn't have run out.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "with a charger that was extremely sensitive"?

Comment: If you touched it gently, it would stop charging the console. And it had to be nudged to the left for it to work. When I nudged it in that direction, that's when I heard the beep.